# jQuery Children selector question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("#Table1 tbody").children().each(function(e){
$(this).bind('click', 
            function(){
                // Do something here
            }, 
            false) 
});
```

The Table1 html table has 2 columns; one for Names and one for a `<button>` element.

When I click on a table row, it works fine.  When I click on the button, the button code fires; however, so does the row code.

How can I filter the selector so the button doesn't trigger the parent element's click event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you want.

It's [stopPropogation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29) that will stop the parents.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>The TD: <input type="button" id="anotherThing" value="dothis"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="results">
  Results:
</div>

<script>

  $(function() {
    $('#anotherThing').click(function(event) {
       $('#results').append('button clicked<br>');
       event.stopPropagation();       
    });
    $('td').click(function() {
       $('#results').append('td clicked<br>');

    });
  });

</script>
```

Here's a link to an example of it working as well:

http://jsbin.com/uyuwi

You can tinker with it at: http://jsbin.com/uyuwi/edit

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like this:

```js
$('#Table1 tr').bind('click', function(ev) {
  return rowClick($(this), ev);
}); //Bind the tr click
$('#Table1 input').bind('click', function(ev) {
  return buttonClick($(this), ev);
}) //Bind the button clicks

function rowClick(item, ev) {
  alert(item.attr('id'));
  return true;
}

function buttonClick(item, ev) {
  alert(item.attr('id'));
  ev.stopPropagation();

  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr1">
      <td>
        The TD: <input type="button" id="button1" value="dothis" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2">
      <td>
        The TD: <input type="button" id="Button2" value="dothis" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to remove the button code and just run the row code, therefore kind of using event bubbling.

Another couple options:

- can you add a class to the TD that has the button in it and in the selector, do `'[class!="className"]'`
- maybe try `event.preventDefault()`. You can see it being [used here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready). this way you can prevent the default action that is triggered when the button is clicked, although I'm not sure if it will completely prevent the bubbling.

Comment: Ultimately, the row on click is a selection action while the button's onclick is a deletion action. I haven't been able to figure out a good way to make such works.